# ¿Cual es el número máximo de usuarios que puede tener una Base de Datos Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, users-roles, usercontrol

Me refiero a usuarios creados con la sentencia: `CREATE USER ...`

De ser ilimitado (o estar limitado por las capacidades de almacenamiento), ¿afectaría al rendimiento tener, por ejemplo, **un millón de usuarios** ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No, no, un millón de usuarios a secas, cada uno con sus privilegios de acceso, un millón de usuarios en la tabla **mysql.user** para que quede claro.

Comment: Bueno, los requisitos de una aplicación pueden ser muy arbitrarios y ese hecho podría darse. Con todos mis respetos, crep que el link no se ajusta a este caso, pues es para el tamaño máximo de una fila en bytes no para  máximo de filas en una tabla.

Comment: Depende. Tener un millón de usuarios es tener un millón de registros en alguna parte y algo más, nada muy grave. USAR un millón de usuarios, depende de cómo se usen, qué los use, etc. Es una pregunta muy amplia más alla del enlace que indican en la respuesta y tiende a recibir opiniones y ejemplos poco concretos.

Comment: Eliminé mi respuesta porque tiende a confundir, más que a aclarar. Te puedes ir con el comentario de Alfabravo como respuesta. Dicho sea de paso,  según la documentación de MySQL, *No hay limitaciones codificadas en el número de usuarios en una base de datos MySQ*